# WordPress: Hide uncategorized category from the_category()

Tags: php, wordpress

I display a list of categories with the `the_category()` function. But there is also the `uncategorized` category listed.

How can I exclude it from here?

I can't remove or rename this category, because I need it at another point.

Comment: This is http://astronautweb.co/snippet/exclude-the_category/ helful for You

Comment: doesnt work... :-(

Comment: Wahat is doesnt work ? Edit Your question and give me example.

Answer (score 2):

I am late but i think i found a good solution that worked for me.

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->name == "Uncategorized") {
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found a good solution to solve this problem...

I give every category a class and hide this class via css.

Here you go: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91260

Answer (score 0):

Try using the filter get_the_category() in place of the_category()

```
add_filter('get_the_categories', 'exc_cat');

function exc_cat($cats) {
        //not on admin pages
        if(!is_admin()){
           $exc = array('uncategorized');
            foreach ($cats as $i=>$cat){
                if(in_array($cat->name, $exc)){
                   unset($cats[$i]); 
                }
            }
        }
    return $cats;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work... if I use get_the_category() in combination with the filter in the functions.php, the single-sites are only white...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it works.

```
if((get_the_category_list() !== 'Uncategorized')){
                            the_category();
                        }
```